# How to get the node position of the element removed from DOMNodeRemoved event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying to determine the document position of the node that is removed from the DOMNodeRemoved event. However, since it is the element being removed, the node no longer holds its previousSibling elements. Is there a way to determine the position of the node removed?

Comment: By position do you mean the index of the element relative to its siblings? Post the code you already have in a fiddle please (and in the question itself).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, by position I  mean its index relative to its siblings

Comment: Check if this is of use http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6xdSN/2/ - it should be very possible to do a non-jQuery version as well.

Comment: If you do not get its position before you remove it, it has no position, parent, nextSibling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer has been shipped using Parcelforce.
Just replace selector $('body').children() and tweak handler function.

```
$.each($('body').children(), function(i,item){item.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',function(e){ console.log('I has been removed'); console.log($(e.target).position());})})
```